# Model Binding not working on MVC postback but formdata appears to be Ok

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class ConfigOptionsViewModel
{
    public List<ConfigOptionGroupViewModel> GroupOptions { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigOptionGroupViewModel
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<ConfigOptionTypeViewModel> ConfigOptionTypes { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigOptionTypeViewModel
{
    public ConfigOptionFieldType Type { get; set; }
    public List<ConfigOptionViewModel> ConfigOptions { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigOptionViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Tooltip { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have this in my view:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.GroupOptions.OrderBy(m => m.GroupName).Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="tab-pane" id="@Model.GroupOptions[i].GroupName">
        @for (var j = 0; j < Model.GroupOptions[i].ConfigOptionTypes.Count; j++)
        {
            for (var k = 0; k < Model.GroupOptions[i].ConfigOptionTypes[j].ConfigOptions.Count; k++)
            {
                if (Model.GroupOptions[i].ConfigOptionTypes[j].Type == ConfigOptionFieldType.String)
                {
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">@Model.GroupOptions[i].ConfigOptionTypes[j].ConfigOptions[k].Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GroupOptions[i].ConfigOptionTypes[j].ConfigOptions[k].Value, new { @class = "m-wrap medium" })
                            <span class="help-block">@Model.GroupOptions[i].ConfigOptionTypes[j].ConfigOptions[k].Tooltip</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        }
    </div>
}
```

When I post for the form however, I only get `GroupOptions` come back with a count of 0.

When I inspect the data posted back, I can see:

```
GroupOptions:System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CC.Web.Areas.Administration.Models.ConfigOption.ConfigOptionGroupViewModel]
GroupOptions[0].ConfigOptionTypes[0].ConfigOptions[0].Value:SomeStr
```

Based on the fact that the `.Value` is posting back with the correct value, I would have this would be enough to bind it.

Could someone kindly explain what I am missing?

Note: I've tried as many variations as I can think of and trying to add hidden fields for all properties but it still fails for some reason.

**EDIT** This is the Model passed to my view:

```
@model CC.Web.Areas.Administration.Models.ConfigOption.ConfigOptionsViewModel
```

This is my post method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddEditStoreConfigOption(ConfigOptionsViewModel configOptionsViewModel)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Where `configOptionsViewModel.GroupOptions.Count` is always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the `if` statement. If the value is `false` then no text box will be rendered and you would get non-consecutive indexers. Indexers must start at zero and be consecutive for the `DefaultModelBinder` to bind collections. To solve this, add an `else` statement to render a hidden input

```
if (Model.GroupOptions[i].ConfigOptionTypes[j].Type == ConfigOptionFieldType.String)
{
  ....
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GroupOptions[i].ConfigOptionTypes[j].ConfigOptions[k].Value, new { @class = "m-wrap medium" })
  ....
}
else
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GroupOptions[i].ConfigOptionTypes[j].ConfigOptions[k].Value
}
```

Comment: No go I'm afraid. Do I need to do anything with the previous lists by posting them back as hidden values or should they post back based on the `.Value` property on the last in the chain of lists? I've posted back complex types before but never lists within lists within lists ...

Comment: I have other values that won't be rendering because of the if. I'm going to clear them out of my data and try again.

Comment: Unless the `if` statement always evaluates to true (which would pointless) then your collections will not post back so that needs to be fixed. I'm not sure why you have `OrderBy(m => m.GroupName)` and if that has any impact.

Comment: I would also suggest you order/filter your model in the controller before sending it to the view.

Comment: Ok, I've cleared down my data so there is only the string type, removed the `if` statement and also removed the `group by` but unfortunately it still refuses to bind.

Comment: Is the ModelBinder clever enough to know how to post back lists within lists? Could this be an issue?

Comment: Yes, you can have nested lists (I have 3 levels in one of my projects). What is the POST method signature and what is the model passed to the view

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. I've added this information to the OP.

Comment: Everything you have posted looks good and if if you first input is `<input ... name="GroupOptions[0].ConfigOptionTypes[0].ConfigOptions.Value" ... />` then it should post back OK. Other issues could be a missing setter on one of the properties

Comment: Ok, sorted it. It was down to some code I had higher up in the view (which I forgot was there). The issue would still have cropped up though had the `if` statement not passed so the hidden value was still required. For info: I was doing `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GroupOptions)` higher up which broke it.